# Refer to Maven project paths from Java

Tags: java, maven, filepath

I need to programmatically gather some paths inside a Maven project, in particular to refer to the project artifact.
Using

```
URL MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource(String name)
```

works for a path relative to the *target/classes* folder of the project, but since the artifact sits in the *target* folder it is not possible to reference it. A path like

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target"
```

does not convince me at all at least for the fact that the *target* folder name, while standard, is not safely portable.

Is there a Maven-aware library solution that exploits a relative path?

Comment: To contextualise: I am trying to automate the loading of (sub)project artifacts for [Pax Exam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam) integration testing. I need to load them from "bare" filesystem paths, since installation is further down in Maven lifecycle.

Comment: What part of the *target* folder name is not portable? The directory separator part, or the fact that the project's output directory can be changed in the project POM?

Comment: I was referring to the project output directory being customisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MavenProperties](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) can be written to a manifest file using the [maven archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestEntries.html) which is used by the maven war plugin or the maven jar plugin.

If you have a web app, then you can pass some information to the web.xml file, too.

This is an example of one of my projects:

```
from pom.xml:
------------------------------------------------
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd.MM.yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <build-version>${env.SVN_REVISION}</build-version>
    <build-date>${maven.build.timestamp}</build-date>
</properties>
.
.
.
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>      
                        <webResource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </webResource>
                    </webResources>

from web.xml:
------------------------------------------------
<context-param>
    <param-name>BUILD_VERSION</param-name>
    <param-value>${build-version}</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>BUILD_DATE</param-name>
    <param-value>${build-date}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: This is a fine general solution, since it allows to import custom properties. I noticed that [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) also abilitates this specific approach. However, since the information I require already lies somewhere in the POM, defining additional properties seems redundant to me.

Comment: `${project.build.outputDirectory}` which results in the path to your "target/classes" directory won't help you? That's one of the maven properties which were "behind" that first link I posted.

Comment: Yes, more precisely, `${project.build.directory}` would. That is not the point. From the second link you provided, it is not clear whether I can build an **additional** Manifest, thus not polluting the one that will be ultimately packaged. The information that I need is for tests.

Comment: I tried that myself - creating or modifying an additional Manifest, but wasn't successful. And I also found no clean way to read information from the MANIFEST.MF file of the war package from my java code. That's the reason for the above solution.